# Making backer board level with old 3/4" sheetrock

Tags: shower

My daughter bought a house that was built in 1940.  We are re-doing the lower walls and tub surround, the latter was collapsing into the tub and held up by Scotch tape.  The lower portion of the room had stamped plaster tiles over a metal mesh, but the top was, to my surprise, sheet rock.  (I didn't know that even existed in 1940, but perhaps it was added later.)  Anyway, this sheet rock is 3/4" thick.  I need to make the cement board level with it.  My preference is to use 1/4" cement board over - something.  I was thinking 1/2" green board.  (I didn't want to shim out all the studs, but I can do that, if necessary.)  I would then waterproof the cement board.  Does that (1/4" cement board over 1/2" green board) sound like a reasonable plan?  I was not planning to put up plastic vapor barrier, btw; it's my understanding that a stud-oriented vapor barrier shouldn't be necessary with sealed cement board.

I will also have to use some similar approach on the remaining lower walls, although I will not need the cement board there.  My original thought was a 1/2" green board topped with 1/4" green board, but I don't see that latter thickness available.  Do I have to shim, instead, or should I be able to use regular 1/4" sheet rock under the green board?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Could you use some of the leftover 1/4" thick lath to shim out the 1/2" green board and get 3/4"?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It was plaster over a wire mesh; there was no wood lath, there.  I could buy wood; I don't mind shimming, but I was concerned about shimming so much and only having 1/4" of cement board as the only solid surface, particularly because it has score marks which seem like an easy thing to snap with some pressure.  The surround is an odd size, or I would use the 1/2".  I don't want to have to cut a lot of 1/2" cement board, as I've read it's quite difficult to cut.  I do want to use cement board and not just green board, btw.  Green board isn't waterproof.